# Tracking Backbone Event via listenTo

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have started working with Backbone.

While learning Backbone, I got to know that the advantage of using .listenTo instead of .on is that listenTo allows "the object to keep track of the events".

I did not got what this sentence is trying to say. Well I can only see the difference between .on and .listenTo is about syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider two calls:

```
this.model.on('change', this.some_method);
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.some_method);
```

In the first case:

1. `this.model` knows that someone is listening for `'change'` events but it doesn't know who.
2. `this` doesn't know what it is listening to unless you explicitly track what `on` calls you've made.

In the second case:

1. `this.model` knows that someone is listening for `'change'` events but it doesn't know who.
2. `this` knows that it is listening to events from `this.model`.

So yes, the syntax is different but the main difference is who knows who is listening: with `on`, only the thing being listened to knows that there is a listener; with `listenTo`, the listener also knows what they're listening to.

The difference is important if you want to stop listening to events. If you're using [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) then you have to maintain your own list of what you're listening to so that you can [`off`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off) them; if you're using [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) then `listenTo` keeps track of that and you can simply [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening).

For example, [`View#remove`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-128) looks like this:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

so you can call `view.remove()` and it will automatically clean up any event bindings you have (as long as you used `listenTo`) and the chance of zombie listeners is drastically reduced.

Comment: O! i got it. Thanks for your guidance. I did not found such details in Backbone Home site itself.

Comment: @iCybernetics: The utility of `listenTo` is easier to see when you used Backbone before there was a `listenTo` method.

Comment: Yes! Got all the information from Change-log provided by Backbonejs.org